# Firebase query result in ListView UI and RecyclerView UI

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am trying to create a Firebase database to store employee information and then when an address is queried, all the employees staying in that particular area should be displayed in a ListView or a RecyclerView however, I am having the following problem:

I am unable to populate the ListView.

```
    ArrayList<String> mItems = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter mAdapter;
    ListView mRecyclerView;

    FirebaseListAdapter<String> fireAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>() {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(View view, String s) {
             //populate view
            }
        };
```

In the above code, I am unable to write the constructor so that it becomes,

```
    FirebaseListAdapter<String> fireAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(this,String.class,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mEmployRef) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(View view, String s) {
                //populate view
            }
        };
```

When I write the above code with the constructor, it says,

Cannot resolve constructor 'FirebaseListAdapter(anonymous             android.view.View.OnClickListener, java.lang.Class, int, com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference)'

How do I resolve this? A similar problem occurs when I try to use a RecyclerView.

Comment: @puf, Sir, can you help with this. I actually followed the Firecast video on this.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating the adapter inside an `OnClickListener()`, which means that `this` points to that listener. You need to pass in the `Activity` to `FirebaseListAdapter`, which you can get with `MainActivity.this`.

Comment: Still gives me the same error sir, FirebaseListAdapter<String> fireAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(Search.this,String.class,...). Doing the above still gives me the same error, pls help. It is true that this is inside the OnClickListener() but passing Search.this gives me the same error.

Comment: @puf, switched over to listView and it works, but not realtime though. But its ok for this app.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem when Firebase upgraded and what i did to get out of the constructor error was change this:

```
Firebase rootRef = new Firebase("https://<your-app>.firebaseio.com/");
```

to this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

then use the rootRef as the fourth parameter on the constructor.

here is a link for upgrading from the previous firebase to the current:
https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android#import_your_project_to_the_new_firebase_console_numbered

Also, upgrade your sdk.  Hope this solves your problem